# get webpage html element values without opening the page in new window or new tab using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Just like the title says I need a way to get the HTML of a webpage with out opening it in a new tab or window. I am making a chrome extension that will take element values from one page and append them to another page.

```
  var htmlObject = gethtml("url");
```

would like some thing like this

Comment: Just a friendly tip, you may want to read over this page: [How-To-Ask Guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you can always be sure that your questions are easily answerable and as clear as possible. Be sure to include any efforts you've made to fix the problem you're having, and what happened when you attempted those fixes. Also don't forget to your code and any error messages!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jQuery to get the content of the webpage:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
var htmlObject;
var yourURL = 'url.html';
$.get(yourURL, function(html) {
  htmlObject = html;
});
```